# Write a cell to file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell <6035x1> like this:

```
1393

01:36:22,080 --> 01:36:25,482

I'm wearing women's underwear. Ha-ha-ha.

1394

01:36:25,640 --> 01:36:28,211

Oh, my God. Ha-ha-ha.

1395

01:36:28,760 --> 01:36:31,843

Stu, don't freak out,

but you need to look down.
```

How can I write to a file?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1CCMDO/index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a loop.

```
data = {'one'; 'two'; 'three'; 'four'};
h = fopen('output2.txt','w+');
n = size(data,1);

for i = 1:n
  fprintf(h, '%s\r\n', data{i});
end

fclose(h);
```

Comment: size(output)

ans =

     1     1

>> size(output{1})

ans =

        6035           1
If my output like this... how can I change??

Comment: Add the line `data = output{1};` before the rest of the code.

Comment: size(data{1})

ans =

     1     4
size(data{15}{1})

ans =

     1    26

How can I fix it??/

Comment: Can you not do `fprintf(h, '%s\n', data{:});` instead of a loop?

Comment: ??? Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

they return this error

Comment: Have edited to let the file open with writing/creation permissions `fopen('output.txt','w+')`. Without it the code won't work for me. Also used `\r\n` to enforce newlines.